# SetInterval slowing down

Tags: javascript, jquery, floating-point, setinterval

After finding out I cannot use vender prefixes in Javascript, I tried to make my own fade-to-blur. After about 5-10 seconds of the script running the `console.log` calls slow to around one per second. Is this something on my end?

Here's the code I've made

```
var i = 0;
var iv = setInterval(function(){
    if(Number(i) > 2)
    {
        clearInterval(iv);
    }

    console.log(i);

    r = i.toFixed(2);

    $('#r').css('filter', 'blur(' + r + 'px)');
    $('#r').css('-webkit-filter', 'blur(' + r + 'px)');
    $('#r').css('-moz-filter', 'blur(' + r + 'px)');
    $('#r').css('-o-filter', 'blur(' + r + 'px)');
    $('#r').css('-ms-filter', 'blur(' + r + 'px)');

    i += 0.01;
}, 1);
```

And a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gMq3P/)

I'm guessing it's the way JS deals with floating-point numbers, also is there any way to get the fade to blurry more smooth? It's quite jumpy once `i` gets to around `0.8`. How do I fix the second delay on the `setInterval`? Can anyone else reproduce this?

---

### Things to note

The same thing occurred while trying to do the same with a for-loop, but it also rendered the page useless until it got to `2` when the loop stopped.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the script faster by caching the calculation of the string 'blur(' + r + 'px)' into a javascript variable and save unwanted calculation.

You can also cache the $('#r') object into a javascript variable or even use the jquery css  multiple-word properties: $('#r').css({propertyName : value , propertyName : value})

Something like:

```
    var calc = 'blur(' + r + 'px)';     
    $('#r').css({
        'filter' :  calc ,
        '-webkit-filter' : calc,
        '-moz-filter' : calc,
        '-o-filter' : calc,
        '-ms-filter' : calc
    });
```

check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/gMq3P/3/